# jQuery <select> value of <form> always null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've done this many times and it's a cinch, but there's something wrong here and I just can't see the problem. When a selection is made from this dropdown list, .value is always null. I know better than that. But I can't see the problem. Does anyone see a problem in this code?

In my _Layout.cshtml I'm calling a Controller Action that returns a partial view:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("LanguageListPartial", "Account");}
```

The Partial View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedLanguage,
    Model.Languages,
    new { @class = "form-control }
)
```

The dropdown renders fine:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="/Account/ListPartial">
    <select name="SelectedLanguage" id="SelectedLanguage">
        <option value="en-US">English</option>
        <option value="fr-CA">Francais</option>
        <option value="pt-BR">Portugues</option>
        <option value="es-MX">Espanol</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="test"></div>
```

**jQuery called on change:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryUI")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#SelectedLanguage').on('change', function () {
                var a = $(this).val();
                $('#test').load("/Account/TestPartial/" + a);
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use .val() instead of .value

Comment: sahbeeway, I tried .val() at first. :S

Comment: then ensure that you have an element somewhere with an id of test

Comment: The down vote is weird (whomever). Seems like a legit question - Code seems ok to me, but just wanted to see if someone else saw a problem with it.

Comment: Where, in you HTML structure, are you placing the `.ready()` function?

Comment: You realize that you're using a DOM ready handler inside of a DOM ready handler.  AFAIK, it's not going to break anything, but it's unnecessarily superfluous.  `$(document).ready(function () {` is exactly the same as `$(function () {`  See:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I am using some example code. I commented out the .ready(). You're right, it didn't break anything that I know of. Commenting it out didn't help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#SelectedLanguage').on('change', function () {
                var a = $(this).val(); 
                $('#test').load("/Account/TestPartial/" + a);
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Could this be an issue somewhere else? Everything works fine, cant test the load partial, but am getting the correct values from your select list, run the fiddle and check your console:

http://jsfiddle.net/2QM28/1/

Comment: I'm just learning MVC so there may be some anomaly. I'll pass it by the MVC community. Thanks Mark. The select is rendered in a Partial View and the script is in the main layout, but the even fires so I don't see why the value wouldn't be available.

Comment: One more thing, maybe try using an ajax async to render the partial..

Ill post one more answer....Ive just started working with mvc myself.

Comment: I've been trying different ideas in the meantime and STARING at this code, but I just don't see what would be causing the .val() and .value to be null.

Comment: @Mark, do you know if jquery.validate.js might interfere? I wouldn't think so, but...

Comment: Also, using FireBug that script doesn't even show up. It must be there since it fires the Controller Action and nothing else is calling it. Still, it doesn't show up in Firebug and I use it a lot to trace through/debug my scripts. :S

Comment: @rwkii, is it possible to move your script into your partial view? You said that it is currently in your layout?

Comment: I really doubt that its the jq validate.

Comment: I moved it to the Partial view but it doesn't fire the Controller Action. Like it's not even there.

Comment: Im sorry, i dont know if there is much more I can do to help you, like I said, Im a front end guy, my mvc knowledge is limited to what ive been working with the last few months, you should repost this question in an with asp.net mvc tags, they will probably be more of a help at this point, im just guessing now.

Comment: Yes, well you gave it a try and hopefully got a few laughs for your involvement. I do appreciate your help and learned at least to things by your answers and comments. ;)

Comment: Yeah, these comments were going nowhere productive, so I cleaned them up. For the record, there's nothing wrong with leaving multiple answers, if the answers are distinct and different.

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion, try ajax asyn update?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#SelectedLanguage').on('change', function () {
                var a = $(this).val(); 
                $.get("~/Account/TestPartial/"+a, function(data){
                 $("#placeholder").html(data);// update existing div
                }):
            });

    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Tracing through this code, still a=null. I think @sahbeewah is on to something with the placement of the .ready().

Comment: Not the issue, but you didn't catch the DOM ready inside of the DOM ready?  `$(document).ready(function () {` is exactly the same as `$(function () {`  See:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/